# What disorder forbids eating raw, but still allow aburi (partially blow-torched or cooked), nigiri?

Tags: raw-food

While at Japanese restaurants, I've overheard at least three different customers  requesting [*aburi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sushi#Neta) for normally raw *nigiri* on the menu, [for medical reasons](https://redd.it/630xhc).

> *Aburi* style refers to *nigiri* sushi where the fish is partially grilled (topside) and partially raw. Most nigiri sushi will have completely raw *neta*.

By the bye, I don't know Wikipedia correctly used "grilled".  These restaurants just blow-torch the top of the *nigiri*.

I still can't figure out what disorder would warrant this distinction between raw and partially cooked *nigiri*? Wouldn't a doctor just advise all such patients vulnerable to foodborne illness to eat only wholly cooked food and to shun anything raw? Thanks!

Comment: To clarify for those of us unfamiliar with Japanese cuisine, does aburi mean only one side is seared and the remaining sides are left untouched by heat?

Comment: @CareyGregory Yes. Thus the chef has already placed the fish on top of the rice. Then the chef blow-torches the top of the entire piece. Thus the side touching the rice remains raw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two types of allergic reactions can occur after eating raw fish:

**1) Anisakis allergy**

According to [The Clinical Characteristics of Anisakis Allergy in Korea (KJIM, 2009)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2698627/), some individuals who have been previously infected with the parasite **Anisakis** after eating *raw* fish can at subsequent consumption of *raw* fish develop a severe allergic reaction to the parasite.

According to [Anisakis simplex: from Obscure Infectious Worm to Inducer of Immune Hypersensitivity (Clinical Microbiology Reviews, 2009)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2292572/), an allergic reaction can be triggered even by dead Anisakis from *cooked* fish.

**2) Oral allergy syndrome**

Some individuals with pollen allergies (allergic rhinitis) or atopic dermatitis (a type of chronic allergic skin reaction with eczema) cross-react with allergens in raw fish. [A 23-year old Japanese woman with allergy to raw fish](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1600-0536.2006.01069.x).

So, with these conditions it's better to avoid raw fish. I can't imagine how would cooking only a half of a fish help in any condition. A half-raw fish is still raw.